# Count the number of unique values by group

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am aware of `combine(groupby(df, :A), nrow=>:count)` to count the number of rows for different `:A`. However, what should be the correct implementation to get the number of unique values of `:B` for different `:A`? Basically, I am looking for the counterpart for R: `df %>% group_by(A) %>% summarize(n_unique = n_distinct(B))`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should be able to do

```
combine(groupby(df, :A), :B => length ∘ unique => :n_distint_B)
```

like this:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = rand(["a", "b"], 20), b = rand(1:5, 20))
20×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b     
     │ String  Int64 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │ a           3
   2 │ b           4
   3 │ a           1
   4 │ a           1
   5 │ b           1
   6 │ a           2
   7 │ b           4
   8 │ a           2
   9 │ b           2
  10 │ b           1
  11 │ b           3
  12 │ b           3
  13 │ a           4
  14 │ a           4
  15 │ b           3
  16 │ b           2
  17 │ a           5
  18 │ a           5
  19 │ b           5
  20 │ a           1

julia> combine(groupby(df, :a), :b => length ∘ unique => :n_distinct_b)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a       n_distinct_b 
     │ String  Int64        
─────┼──────────────────────
   1 │ a                  5
   2 │ b                  5
```

Comment: Hi Nils, that solves my question exactly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution using double `groupby`-`combine` strategy that is slightly faster:

```
julia> df = repeat(DataFrame(a = rand(["a", "b"], 20), b = rand(1:5, 20)), 10^6);

julia> @btime combine(groupby($df, :a), :b => length ∘ unique => :n_distinct_b);
  650.915 ms (237 allocations: 866.37 MiB)

julia> @btime combine(groupby(combine(groupby($df, [:a, :b]), nrow), :a), nrow => :n_distinct_b);
  457.884 ms (346 allocations: 561.20 MiB)
```

(but what Nils proposed is more natural)